# Updating Editor and Modified for a publishing page

Tags: 2010, publishing-page

I'm trying to update a publishing page in SharePoint 2010 with new `Editor` and `Modified` values, but the ones I pass (that I copy from another page) are not saved.

I've tried `Update()`, `SystemUpdate()`, `UpdateOverwriteVersion()` - nothing works. Is there a secret trick? I've tried the suggestions in other similar questions but the situations are a bit different.

Code snippet below:

```
...
$page = $web.Lists["Pages"].GetItemByUniqueId($uid)
$page["Editor"] = $e      # user from another page
$page["Modified"] = $m    # date from another page
$page.SystemUpdate($false)
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple example works for me:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb 'http://aissp2013'
$list = $web.Lists["Pages"]
$page = $list.GetItemById(4)
$user = $web.EnsureUser('contoso\aaronp')
$page["Editor"] = $user   
$page["Modified"] = '11/14/2014' 
$page.SystemUpdate()
```

Answer (score 0):

Five years ago I created a [custom field type](https://pholpar.wordpress.com/category/custom-fields/) to support changing those props from the UI. I've based my solution on the code sample found [here](http://www.sharepointblogs.be/blogs/vandest/archive/2009/04/13/sharepoint-2007-update-system-properties-created-created-by-modified-modified-by.aspx):

```
SPListItem item = ...; 
item["Created By"] = web.EnsureUser("luisb").ID; 
item["Modified By"] = item["Modified By"]; 
item["Created"] = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-3); 
item["Modified"] = DateTime.Parse("01/01/2000"); 
item.UpdateOverwriteVersion();
```

As you can see, it utilizes the UpdateOverwriteVersion method, and not the Update / SystemUpdate methods.