# How to update Created By Author field in list SharePoint 2013 JavaScript Client Object Model

Tags: list, javascript, sharepoint-online, client-object-model, updatelistitems

Just wanting to know how to update a user field, like CreatedBy or Author based on a users name e.g. *steven.martin*? I seem to have it working fine, from a user id, but not from a user name.

**get user fields by id**

```
var context = new SP.ClientContext();
var user = context.get_web().getUserById(30); // e.g. user id = 30
context.load(user);
context.executeQueryAsync( 
  function () {
    console.log(user.get_email());
    var userField = user.get_id() + ";#" + user.get_loginName();
    updateUser(userField);
   },
   function (sender, args) {
     console.log('Error retrieving user properties');
   }
);
```

**update user/ author field**

```
function updateUser(userField) {
  var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext("/");
  var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Announcments");
  var listItem = {};
  listItem = list.addItem(new SP.ListItemCreationInformation());
  listItem.set_item('Title', "My Announcement");
  listItem.set_item("Author", userField);
  listItem.update();                

  clientContext.executeQueryAsync( 
    function (sender, args) {
      console.log('successfully updated');
    }, 
    function (sender, args) {
      console.log('Request failed, adding new list item');                  
    }
  );

}
```

Comment: You can achieve similar functionality Using REST API for Sharepoint Online. You can find code snippet at [Update Editor and Author Filed](https://anomepani.github.io/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I did it like this, although I think Vadim's approach may also be correct, I couldn't get it to work myself.

**get user id by name**

```
function getUserId = function (userName) {              

  var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  var web = clientContext.get_web();
  var currentUser = web.ensureUser(userName);
  clientContext.load(web);
  clientContext.load(currentUser);
  clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {
    var userid = currentUser.get_id();
      // now you have the id, get the user field to update author
      getUserById(userid);
    }, function (sender, args) {
      console.log('failed to get the current user');
    }); 
}
```

**get user fields by id**

```
function getUserById(userid) {
  var context = new SP.ClientContext();
  var user = context.get_web().getUserById(30); // e.g. user id = 30
  context.load(user);
  context.executeQueryAsync( 
    function () {
      // now you have the user id and correct login name, update author
      var userField = user.get_id() + ";#" + user.get_loginName();
      updateUser(userField);
     },
     function (sender, args) {
       console.log('Error retrieving user properties');
     }
  );
}
```

**update user/ author field**

```
function updateUser(userField) {
  var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext("/");
  var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Announcments");
  var listItem = {};
  listItem = list.addItem(new SP.ListItemCreationInformation());
  listItem.set_item('Title', "My Announcement");
  listItem.set_item("Author", userField);
  listItem.update();                

  clientContext.executeQueryAsync( 
    function (sender, args) {
      console.log('successfully updated');
    }, 
    function (sender, args) {
      console.log('Request failed, adding new list item');                  
    }
  );

}
```

So calling `getUserId("steven.martin")` will update in this case the list item with the author field, rather than giving the author who actually created the item.

**Note:** I actually passed in a callback function to `getUserId` and `getUserById` so I could call the function and on success get the user field which I can use to update the list item. So I can call a general `getUser` function like this `getUser("steven.martin", function () { /* update list item */})`

Answer (score 1):

Updating this field requires the [*UpdateOverwriteVersion*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.updateoverwriteversion.aspx) method when working on the server side ([see sample](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/121178/updating-editor-and-modified-for-a-publishing-page)). Since this method (or the *SystemUpdate* method) is not available in the client OM, I am a bit sceptic that you can achieve your goal.

It's not clear, what you would like to achieve with this code:

```
var userField = user.get_id() + ";#" + user.get_loginName() + ";" + user.get_id() + ";#" + user.get_loginName();
```

Is it a copy-paste failure, or you would like to store the same user twice in the same single user field?

why not simply:

```
var userField = user.get_id() + ";#" + user.get_loginName();
```

Comment: thank for that, yes it was a copy paste error I meant `var userField = user.get_id() + ";#" + user.get_loginName();` will update my question. I think I have found a way to do it, by first querying the user with web.ensureUser(userName). I will post an answer once I have it working

Answer (score 1):

You could utilize [SP.FieldUserValue.fromUser Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj838503.aspx) for that purpose, for example:

```
var authorVal = SP.FieldUserValue.fromUser(userName);
listItem.set_item('Author', authorVal);
```

**Complete example**

```
var properties = {};
properties['Title'] = 'Request N#789';
properties['Author'] = SP.FieldUserValue.fromUser('i:0#.f|membership|username@tenant.onmicrosoft.com');



createListItem('Requests',properties,
     function(item) {
          console.log('Request has been created');        
     },
     function logError(sender, args) {
        console.log(args.get_message());
     }
   );
```

where

```
function createListItem(listTitle,itemProperties,success,error)
{
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    var itemCreateInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
    var listItem = list.addItem(itemCreateInfo);
    for(var propName in itemProperties) {
       listItem.set_item(propName, itemProperties[propName]) 
    }
    listItem.update();
    context.executeQueryAsync(
      function() {
          success(listItem);
      },
      error);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it looks like a good solution, but is not working for me, possibly something to do with the `i:0#.f` part, it does not match up to what I get when I call `user.get_loginName()`. So for now I am using the solution to get the id from the user name, and then get the user field by id, I am passing in a callback to update my list item, so I just need to call `getUser("steven.martin", function () { /* update list item */})`