# How to use Item.SystemUpdate() with SharePoint REST API?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

SharePoint REST API update modified date for the items, but I need to make change without update the date, how I can do this with REST API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, and as I have already wrote in [this thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/134043/how-to-update-created-by-author-field-in-list-sharepoint-2013-javascript-client), the `SystemUpdate` and the `UpdateOverwriteVersion` methods are not implemented in the Client OM and in the REST API. If you decompile the `Microsoft.SharePoint` assembly (for example using `Reflector` or `JetBrains dotPeek`), you can see the lack of the attributes on these methods, that would be needed to client access.

Comment: As of August 2016, CSOM in SharePoint Online does support SystemUpdate. http://dev.office.com/blogs/new-sharepoint-csom-version-released-for-Office-365-august-2016-updated

Answer (score 0):

This worked like a charm!

```
                item["StatusIndicator"] = "Red";
                item["Modified"] = item["Modified"];
                item["Created"] = item["Created"];
                item["Editor"] = item["Editor"];
                item["Author"] = item["Author"];
                item.Update();
                context.Load(item);
                context.ExecuteQuery();
```